# what does PHP waste my system memory on?

Tags: php, memory

I have an Apache server with PHP/MySQL on Windows (32-bit). I try to run the fallowing code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>DBAdmin</title>
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- a lot of only-HTML code here -->

    [...]

    memory usage:
    <?php echo memory_get_usage(); ?> byte
</body>
</html>
```

the value returned by memory_get_usage() is nearly 78 kb. when i run the same code on x64 Windows with the same server, this number is even becomes about 329 kb.

So, i would like to know what is this much of memory wasted on (by the script!)?

Comment: Is the first result got on windows 32bit or some another OS?

Comment: But in any case - 300kb is a very small amount of memory. In just 100mb you could fit 300 simultaneous clients. It is not likely you'll ever have so much and your server could handle the load they would generate.

Comment: In the grand scheme of things 78 or even 329 kb isn't a big deal. Have you looked in the task manager to see what applications like instant messenger or text editors take when they're sitting there doing nothing?

Comment: There's always going to be *something* going on, like simply storing the populated `$_SERVER` array for the request in memory, plus some overhead. A few hundred kilobyte is hardly "wasting" anything.

Comment: I love somebody running their web server on __Windows__ complaining about a few hundred k of memory usage being wasted

Comment: @zerkms both results i got from Windows

Comment: I agree guys, but if the script allocates this amount of memory by doing nothing, try to imagine what it would be when i fill in my page with my CMS (that's what the page will become) functionality! Add to this picture a lot of users and my shared hosting will not forgive me :)

Comment: @字姓名 - given that 70% of the Internet seems to manage running some incredibly complex and powerful scripts with this memory-wasteful language without too many problems, then I don't think you need to be overly-concerned for your own site.

Comment: @MarkBaker i hope so... Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Mark Baker in what way is PHP memory wasteful? Because it's interpreted, or are you implying something about the underlying engineering of the > PHP 5.3 interpreter?

Comment: @dqhendricks - I won't answer that on the grounds that I was being facetious

Comment: @Mark Baker heh, got it.

Answer (score 1):

The memory usage on a 64 bit system will be higher than a 32 bit system because some of the internal structures that PHP needs to build to parse your file take more space in RAM (eg, the maximum size of an integer on 64 bit PHP is larger than in 32 bit PHP).

The difference here is trivial and not exponential (ie, 64 bit PHP runtime might have a larger footprint, but won't use double the memory compared to a 32 bit PHP runtime).